# Как парсить контент, который ещё не подгрузился?

Tags: javascript, php

Есть сайт (https://mangalib.me/little-angel-and-good-devil/v1/c147/denoncomics?page=1), на нём находится манга (комикс, если так понятнее), как можно спарсить все страницы (картинки) к себе на сайт, учитывая так же томы с другими страницами?

Всё это нужно реализовать на php.

Comment: В чем проблема прямого парсинга, если страницы отличаются только get-параметром `page`? Просто делайте запрос в цикле, меняя значение `page`.

Comment: Используйте XMLReader https://habr.com/ru/post/330240/

Answer (score 4):

Можно все реализовать намного проще. На [главной странице](https://mangalib.me/little-angel-and-good-devil/) конкретно этой манги имеется полный список томов с главами. Откуда их можно скачать по прямой ссылке. Но, если это необходимо делать не в ручную, то:

1. Можно сначала парсить их список и достать с каждого такой атрибут, как `data-id`.

   Тут небольшой код, который парсит нужные значения атрибута и собирает в массив.

   ```
   $path = file_get_contents('https://mangalib.me/little-angel-and-good-devil/');

   $doc = new DOMDocument();
   libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
   $doc->loadHTML($path);
   libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

   $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

   $data_ids = [];
   foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="chapter-item"]/@data-id') as $tag) {
       $data_ids[] = $tag->value;
   }

   print_r($data_ids);
   ```

   Чтобы вам не мучаться пилить велики :)
2. Имея собранный массив со значением атрибута, мы делаем запрос к странице:

   ```
   https://mangalib.me/download/дата-ид
   ```

   На этой странице мы получаем данные в формате `json`и массив с
   названиями картинок.
3. Далее мы переходим по следующей ссылке:

   ```
   https://img2.mangalib.me/manga/little-angel-and-good-devil/chapters/дата-ид/нейм-фото
   ```

   Скачиваем таким способом все остальные картинки.